# Display Product(Object) info when user clicks on it

Tags: python, html, django

Right now I'm making an ecommerce store, but I can't wrap my head around displaying specific object info (in this case a Product instance) when a user clicks on it. So here's my views.py:

```
def product_page(request):
    all_products = Product.objects.all()
    quantity_forms = QuantityForms(request.POST)
    quantity = request.POST.get('amount')
    grand_total = RevenueInfo.user_total
    current_user = request.user
    #buyer = User.
    if quantity > 0:
        #ExtendedProfile().amount_spent += (quantity * Product.price_CAD)
        #RevenueInfo().user_total += int(quantity)
        return HttpResponse(current_user.product_set.all()[0].description)
    return render(request,'tracker/product_page.html', {'all_products':all_products, 'quantity_forms':quantity_forms})

def product_details(request, object_id):
    product = object_id
    return render(request, 'tracker/product_details.html', {'product':product})
```

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    purchase = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through="Purchases")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    #photo = models.ImageField()
    price_CAD = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=0, null=True, editable=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product_details")
```

And my `product_page.html`:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% for object in all_products %}
<h3><a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ object.name }}</a></h3>
<p>{{ object.description }}</p>
<p>{{ object.price_CAD }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

Basically I'm not getting the logical flow of information, by `get_absolute_url` is running in my `Product` model when I click on one of the product links, which references my `product_details` view, but from there how do I refer to the individual product instance that was clicked on, then display it's unique attributes in a different template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.urls import reverse
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('product_details', args=[self.id])
```

you can simply do this in your models where you are defining `get_absolute_url` and on template keep it as it is, now on click it will redirect to the specific object

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, sorry I was working all day. I've used that before as per the docs but I keep getting the error: ` Reverse for 'product_details' with arguments '('1',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tracker/product_details']`

Comment: its only when I add the `args=[str(self.id)]`

Comment: have edited the ans, maybe the error was because of str representation of the id, try this and let me know if the error still remains @Amon

Comment: Thanks after you posted the answer I tried changing my url regex to what Amarpreet said, both of your answers seem to be working now. Just one more question though: I'm able successfully display the id of the object, but how do I display each attribute as I please?

Comment: in the details page??

Comment: the way you are displaying the id bro. like {{ object.name }} for name and same for other fields too

Comment: That's what I though but I must be missing something, nothing is being displayed when I do that. I thought there was a problem with the context I was passing in my `product_details` view so I changed it, check my edit

Comment: you are only sending the id, thus nothing is displayed, query the database like some = Model.object.get(id=object_id), then send the variable in the context, then do {{ some.name }} in the template

Comment: Ahh that's what I was missing, thanks a lot man it works now. That makes sense. I think the `object_id` confused me, I haven't referred to an id like that yet, I'm not sure why it's different than say `object.id`

Comment: object_id is a variable bro and object.id returns the id associated with the particular object

Comment: Okay, it's just that `object_id` was never defined anywhere when I put it in my urls.py. Does django automatically recognize it?

Comment: yes, the patthern in which you are passing the variable name needs to be passed to the view function as well, then it will work, lik in url P<id>, then def some(request,id) needs to be passed

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass some unique product id when user clicks on link

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'your url' object.id %}">{{ object.name }}</a></h3>
```

Then in urls.py send the same in url

```
url(r'^(?P<object_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Now in view you can use the object_id as

```
def detail(request, object_id):
```